# django choices in usercreationform

Tags: django

I tried a lot of ways to add a choice field on the registration field, but only the `forms.ChoiceField` is not showing up. Even the HTML is on the page but not rendering.

```
class NewUserForm(UserCreationForm):

    Choices = (('I', "International"), ('K', "Korean"))
    EXAMPLE = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
    you_are = forms.ChoiceField(choices=Choices)

    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = ("username", "password1", "password2", "you_are")

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(NewUserForm, self).save(commit=False)
        if commit:
            if user.you_are == "K":
                user.lang = "KR"
            user.save()
        return user
```

Then the `EXAMPLE` part shows up, but not the `you_are` part.

Are there any problems with my code? Or do I have to use a different way to include `forms.ChoiceField`?

Answer (score 0):

It was a problem that is caused by a conflict(`display:none`) with `materialize.min.css` and `django.UserCreationForm`.

I solved it by overriding display settings by manually changing the local select.html file in the django library.